# UIbutton forgets width and height

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I set the UIbutton to a frame width and height using the following:

```
let button = UIButton()
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 31, height: 31) //set the frame
```

and that works.

[image]

However when I close the app and reopen I get this strange thing happening where the app can't remember the width and height of the button.

and instead does this (see image) instead of staying in the 31 by 31.

[image: the right button]

Now how have I set this button?

With the following code.

```
// Image needs to be added to project.
                     let button = UIButton()
                     button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 31, height: 31) //set the frame
                     // let modifier = AnyImageModifier { return $0.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) }
                     button.kf.setImage(with: fburl, for: .normal, placeholder: nil)
                     button.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("yourActionFunc")), for: .touchUpInside)
                     let barButton = UIBarButtonItem()
                     barButton.customView = button
                     self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
                    //END FACEBOOK PROFILE IMAGE
```

I don't believe it has anything to do with the code above I thought it was something about the function:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    print(defaults.string(forKey: defaultsKeys.socialLogin))
     self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "DRN1"
    let sessionsocial = self.defaults.string(forKey: defaultsKeys.socialLogin)
    if sessionsocial == nil {
     // Image needs to be added to project.
     let buttonIcon = UIImage(systemName: "person.circle")

    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Person", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.done, target: self, action: #selector(FirstViewController.checkLogin(_:)))
     rightBarButton.image = buttonIcon

      self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
       //self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(systemName: "ng")
    //self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: "person.circle", target: self, action: nil)

    }
  }
```

But I know it is not running that code, because I would see a person.circle image instead of my big head. How can I solve this strange issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to set the frame of the button manually you need to do it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` so that it gets set correctly every time the parent view's frame changes.  The idiomatically correct way to do it though is to use auto layout instead of manual frame sizing.

Comment: Ok but how do you set the button after the button already set? like I get it if this was HTML and CSS it has an ID. but this just has a   self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem - I take it you can't redo it once it has been set?

Comment: so what I am hearing people say is that store the users profile image in a session and then re-create the button in viewDidLayoutSubview? would that be correct?